# Simple_html_dom: HTTPS error - file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, ssl, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

So I used simple_html_dom on a http page, and everything worked fine, but now it has changed to https:// which gives me an error I cant find a fix for here on stackoverflow.

I cant figure out where to change the code so it works with https. All the other questions here are using the function `file_get_contents();` and im not.

Im giving the error:
"Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in..."

index.php

```
$target_url = "https://example.dk";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
```

Simple_html_dom.php

```
// load html from file
function load_file() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $this->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
}
```

Comment: The problem is still the same - the certificate validation failed because something is wrong with the certificate or your CA store. What exactly is wrong is unknown but maybe posting of the URL in question would help.

Comment: You could use curl and disable peer verify.

Comment: I made it work using cURL.. thanks :)